# Multiple chrome instances using docker (ubuntu/Windows)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

My case:

I have a project that parses the website using selenium chrome driver. Currently, I am using 5 computers under Windows OS (1 physical and 4 VM inside the physical). I am using this setup because of the captcha, so each machine has its own public IP (using VPN).

I was thinking of enlarging this project under docker and want to ensure some aspects.

1. Is it possible to have a docker(windows instances) that acts like a VM (like has graphical interface, installation VPN and so on)? I am thinking because, VM are seems to be resource intensive (only difference is IP and separate chrome driver).
2. Docker seems to more friendly with ubuntu. Can I setup one ubuntu and create N number of docker with its own VPN, but use chrome driver of the main ubuntu machine?
3. Can I access those docker via anydesk, or smth like that? Graphical interface is important for now. (In the future planning to test with headless mode).

Thanks in advance!

I have read some materials but i am confused a liitle.

Answer (score 0):

1. While it [looks like some people do run *GUI* applications with **Docker**](https://www.google.com/search?q=running+GUI+with+Docker), this is not the common usage. The short answer would be *no* for *GUI*s.
2. VMs ***are*** resource intensive. Using containers has many [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine): lightweight, start faster, easy to move/share, ...
3. **Docker** ***is*** more friendly with **Linux** distributions. The developer experience can easily be awful on non-Linux OS.
4. You can start multiple containers of the same image, manually or using [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). You just need to make sure there's no [port mapping conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281970/how-do-i-avoid-port-collision-when-using-docker).
5. Again, probably no GUI available but headless tools using W3C WebDrivers still allow taking screenshots like [Panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther).

I can't answer about VPNs as I have no knowledge about them.